# How to hide entity object in ursina engine python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.8, ursina

I want to create a flashlight, when you press 1 beam appears, but I want it to disappear after a second. I made it, but my code doesn't work.
My code:

````
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
def flashlight(): # flashlight code
    f = Entity(model='sphere', scale=4, color=color.light_gray) 
    time.sleep(1.0) #pause
    f.visible = False #disappearing

def update(): 
    if held_keys['1']:  flashlight() 
app.run()```
````

Comment: @robt228 Exactly, what is the problem in your code ? To let others understand, update the post with your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `Entity` appear and disappear after **1 second**, you can use Ursina' [invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59979404/17675859) function. Here is its implementation in your code:

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
def test_func(e):
    e.visible = False
def flashlight(): # flashlight code
    f = Entity(model='sphere', scale=4, color=color.azure) 
    invoke(test_func, f, delay=.2)



def update(): 
    if held_keys['1']:  flashlight()

EditorCamera()
app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you,  and Can you advise how to make the flashlight effect? to be translucent

Comment: @robot228 To make the flashlight effect translucent, you can change the `alpha` value of it's color. You can paste this code before the invoke function `f.color = color.rgba(255, 255, 255, 10)`